# How to convert background-image CSS with linear-gradient to SASS?

Tags: sass

How to convert the `css` below into `scss` ?

```
background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      180deg,
      hsl(0, 0%, 78%) 0%,
      hsl(0, 0%, 90%) 47%,
      hsl(0, 0%, 78%) 53%,
      hsl(0, 0%, 70%) 100%
    );
```

So that it can replace `background: red` in my `scss` below:

```
$material-light: (
  background: red,
);
$material-dark: (
  background: #00ff00,
);
```

Comment: Why would you use -webkit-prefixed property values in the same declaration as the non-prefixed version?

Comment: @connexo Indeed, the `-webkit` properties are actually unnecessary. I have updated my post.

Comment: I haven't worked with SCSS for some years, but aren't SCSS variables meant to contain *values* rather than *declarations*?

Comment: Do you mean writing it as classes or as variables value to use them in a framework?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add it to the map just wrapp it in one line.

You may do:

```
$material-light: (
    background-image: 'linear-gradient(180deg, hsl(0, 0%, 78%) 0%, hsl(0, 0%, 90%) 47%,hsl(0, 0%, 78%) 53%, 0%, 70%) 100%)',
);
```